# Convert javascript string formated like array to array object

Tags: javascript, json

I have receive a string with this format

```
"{'key': value}, {'key': value},{'key': value} ..."
```

I need to convert this string to javascript array to use like this:

```
var $arrayValue = [{'key': value}, {'key': value},{'key': value}];
```

how to conver this string into array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string = string = '{"key": "value"}, {"key": "value"}'
JSON.parse("[" + string + "]")
```

Comment: *Assuming you can be sure each object is valid JSON,* this is the best way to do it.

Comment: The console get me this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '

Comment: This is because you're passing in single quoted JSON keys/values. Use double quotes.

Comment: This string is a variable extracted from json query, this is automatically extracted with string double quotes "{'key': value}", if i replace the single quote with double this string fail:

string = string = "{"key": "value"}, {"key": "value"}"

notice the double quotes before and after string :S

Comment: Instead your example code, I have this:
string = string = myVariable;
JSON.parse("[" + string + "]")

This variable is automatically placed with double quotes "",